# Creating a raw Segwit transaction from scratch and getting Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation

Tags: transactions, segregated-witness, multi-signature, signature, createrawtransaction

I am trying to create a Segwit transaction on TESTNET from scratch while referencing an online guide:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/creating-and-signing-a-segwit-transaction-from-scratch-ec98577b526a

My BIP-39 mnemonics code:

```
differ toast alert candy orbit raccoon wagon hour thunder kiwi home cigar
```

My TESTNET BIP-32 master public key derived Segwit Bech32 address with derivation path 'm':

```
tb1qzjgctgz9t98dmkwp4z26whg6tl4w9s6rl6hwwj
```

The address profile can be viewed from [here](https://blockstream.info/testnet/address/tb1qzjgctgz9t98dmkwp4z26whg6tl4w9s6rl6hwwj).

Just for simplicity of debugging, the derivation 'm' will be used only.

For more context the Master Public Key compressed format:

```
03D7DE86033E1C815BA0E3589938B7AC906B728F1F2C771542E203E32B80A3385A
```

For more context the Master Public Key uncompressed format:

```
04D7DE86033E1C815BA0E3589938B7AC906B728F1F2C771542E203E32B80A3385AE1DEED79187355D35FDABAF74DFD186A8B8C9FE1D6357AA46750A47B86ED16CF
```

The raw BIP-32 Seed:

```
1CD4561EF82D35F9EE2E95ED63B68BB91ADA8967E1D98FA4080637A4CC310BE99DD285F82F45EE004ADC408F8B93C2A829A5B811104496A6FB0301E062CBC813
```

The raw Master Private Key used for the digital signing later:

```
13D84CAC526896CEF2594D71621D2AEDC90F9DAEA88A1751AD99E35868E0021B
```

I would like to send myself (tb1qzjgctgz9t98dmkwp4z26whg6tl4w9s6rl6hwwj) some funds (0x5503000000000000 / 853 satoshis) using my own address (tb1qzjgctgz9t98dmkwp4z26whg6tl4w9s6rl6hwwj).

So, I begin to create the Segwit inputs that would then be double-SHA256 hashed then signed.

It follows the BIP143 defined steps:

```
Double SHA256 of the serialization of:
 1.  nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
 2.  hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
 3.  hashSequence (32-byte hash)
 4.  outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 
 5.  scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)
 6.  value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)
 7.  nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)
 8.  hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
 9.  nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
 10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)

// 1.  nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
<<< 01000000

// 2.  hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
>>> printf "4E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0 00000000" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b

<<< 04dc164c0a705f5d2d57fd42e6896a94394e6966ed0b116a64adfaa9310b848f

//  3.  hashSequence (32-byte hash)

>>> printf "ffffffff" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum | xxd -p -r | sha256sum

<<< 3bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e70665044

//  4.  outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 

<<< 4E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0 00000000

//  5.  scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)

<<< 1976a914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388ac

//  6.  value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)

<<< e803000000000000

//  7.  nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)

<<< ffffffff

// 8.  hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
          
>>> printf "e803000000000000 16 0014149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C343" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b

<<< 7c007a193409e64199438db0ba4349809fbcc42c17e7167cbc06deec4cc0998f

// 9.  nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
<<< 00000000

// 10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)
<<< 01000000

// Hashing with double Sha256

>>> printf 0100000004dc164c0a705f5d2d57fd42e6896a94394e6966ed0b116a64adfaa9310b848f3bb13029ce7b1f559ef5e747fcac439f1455a2ec7c5f09b72290795e706650444E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0000000001976a914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388ace803000000000000ffffffff7c007a193409e64199438db0ba4349809fbcc42c17e7167cbc06deec4cc0998f0000000001000000 | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b

<<< c2636fae9487354f47e4e92458a7e856f717533c6d01e1c5fda5b06c4a1976a8
```

The encoded digital signature result:

```
30450221008B61503427B2292F781405712DF878B207D8B89FC86D60B1A68D479CA6C6FF2302203BB1F7F5F7E2B9050BA481310C997F6F078F5ED25564AEC85277EB56BA98FD76
```

Finally, formatted into a raw transaction below:

```
010000000001014E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A00000000000FFFFFFFF015503000000000000160014149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C343024830450221008B61503427B2292F781405712DF878B207D8B89FC86D60B1A68D479CA6C6FF2302203BB1F7F5F7E2B9050BA481310C997F6F078F5ED25564AEC85277EB56BA98FD76012103D7DE86033E1C815BA0E3589938B7AC906B728F1F2C771542E203E32B80A3385A00000000
```

The broadcast results throws the following error:

```
sendrawtransaction RPC error: {"code":-26,"message":"non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Signature must be zero for failed CHECK(MULTI)SIG operation)"}
```

I have checked the digital signatures many times and ran validation on the signatures and public key with assumption that all the above addresses and scripts are valid.

How do I fix the failed broadcast ? What are the causes of the failed broadcast ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, finally I got some things to work and there are quite some changes I had to make but it seems to have work.

I need to retrace my steps all over again later on tomorrow as its late now.

Here's the TESTNET transaction txid: [e559b79981b5bcde2df389f37e2b72e5d6a132748c6dab499d10f5186568533f](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/e559b79981b5bcde2df389f37e2b72e5d6a132748c6dab499d10f5186568533f)

Also, while trying every means to mint this transaction, it raises more questions than answers at the same time. There's quite a few "waht-ifs corner cases" I have in mind.

Firstly, I need to create a PEM file containing the private key so that I can use OpenSSL to sign the transaction later on. This is an optional step.

```
printf "302e0201010420 13D84CAC526896CEF2594D71621D2AEDC90F9DAEA88A1751AD99E35868E0021B a00706052b8104000a" | xxd -p -r > priv1.hex

openssl ec -inform d < priv1.hex > priv1.pem
```

The private key in the original post is added into a PEM format file. If you are not using OpenSSL to sign, you can omit this step.

Next is the usual layout of 10 steps.

```
// 1.  nVersion of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
<<< 01000000

// 2.  hashPrevouts (32-byte hash)
>>> printf "4E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0 00000000" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b

<<< 04dc164c0a705f5d2d57fd42e6896a94394e6966ed0b116a64adfaa9310b848f

//  3.  hashSequence (32-byte hash)

>>> printf "FDFFFFFF" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum | xxd -p -r | sha256sum

<<< caf35e5224de16efa3ccaf41070f6e7b9432b6f79551e629fca9d1c03b43bc52

//  4.  outpoint (32-byte hash + 4-byte little endian) 

<<< 4E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0 00000000

//  5.  scriptCode of the input (serialized as scripts inside CTxOuts)

<<< 1976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC

//  6.  value of the output spent by this input (8-byte little endian)

<<< e803000000000000

//  7.  nSequence of the input (4-byte little endian)

<<< FDFFFFFF

// 8.  hashOutputs (32-byte hash)
          
>>> printf "01000000000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC54030000000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC" | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b

<<< 91f7bd32e352f7cc0cb49cbdf9f7d0f51f27a4da527c094b2ab85c2e2e0ae47f

// 9.  nLocktime of the transaction (4-byte little endian)
<<< 00000000

// 10. sighash type of the signature (4-byte little endian)
<<< 01000000
```

Next is the serialization of the hash pre-image by concatenating all the steps results above:

```
0100000004dc164c0a705f5d2d57fd42e6896a94394e6966ed0b116a64adfaa9310b848fcaf35e5224de16efa3ccaf41070f6e7b9432b6f79551e629fca9d1c03b43bc524E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388ACe803000000000000FDFFFFFF91f7bd32e352f7cc0cb49cbdf9f7d0f51f27a4da527c094b2ab85c2e2e0ae47f0000000001000000
```

Next is the double hashing of the hash pre-image:

```
// Double hashing and storing double hashed result

>>> printf 0100000004dc164c0a705f5d2d57fd42e6896a94394e6966ed0b116a64adfaa9310b848fcaf35e5224de16efa3ccaf41070f6e7b9432b6f79551e629fca9d1c03b43bc524E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388ACe803000000000000FDFFFFFF91f7bd32e352f7cc0cb49cbdf9f7d0f51f27a4da527c094b2ab85c2e2e0ae47f0000000001000000 | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r | sha256sum -b | xxd -p -r > msg-segwit
```

Next is using the PEM private key to sign in OpenSSL with a SHA-256 digest:

```
// Signing

>>> openssl pkeyutl -inkey priv1.pem -sign -in msg-segwit -pkeyopt digest:sha256 | xxd -p -c 256

<<< 30450221008f56dd07c3637ba6bc00e4e8e05bd2e9c3d6a5c073201df8aaf52e9847d0e01c0220752381278c83287c975a147b20daef443f68d85c84650ab2d061375b6f6ef739
```

Append your sighash (SIGHASH_ALL - 0x01) to the back of the signature:

```
<<< 30450221008f56dd07c3637ba6bc00e4e8e05bd2e9c3d6a5c073201df8aaf52e9847d0e01c0220752381278c83287c975a147b20daef443f68d85c84650ab2d061375b6f6ef739 01
```

Finally, serialize and merge all the transaction data with the digital signature into a single transaction:

```
// Serialization

01000000 // version
0001 // witness

01 // 1 input

4E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A0 00000000 // outpoint with output index
00 // 0 bytes script
FDFFFFFF // sequence

02 // 2 outputs

0100000000000000 // output amount
1976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC // output script
5403000000000000 // output amount
1976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC // output script

02 // First input has witness script of 2 elements

48 // signature length
30450221008f56dd07c3637ba6bc00e4e8e05bd2e9c3d6a5c073201df8aaf52e9847d0e01c0220752381278c83287c975a147b20daef443f68d85c84650ab2d061375b6f6ef739 01 // signature with sighash (01) 
21 // compressed pubkey length
03D7DE86033E1C815BA0E3589938B7AC906B728F1F2C771542E203E32B80A3385A // compressed pubkey

00000000 // Locktime

<<< 010000000001014E2F5CCED0DC6D7B229AB43381A7DDBAB759C457C3366D8435782120493133A00000000000FDFFFFFF0201000000000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC54030000000000001976A914149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C34388AC024830450221008f56dd07c3637ba6bc00e4e8e05bd2e9c3d6a5c073201df8aaf52e9847d0e01c0220752381278c83287c975a147b20daef443f68d85c84650ab2d061375b6f6ef739012103D7DE86033E1C815BA0E3589938B7AC906B728F1F2C771542E203E32B80A3385A00000000
```

End Result:

- A transaction (txid is on top of this post in the link) manages to fire off successfully.
- The targeted receipt addresses are INCORRECT in the transaction. I will need to figure out again on the txouts side and update here again.

What changed:

- Step 3 & 7. Hash Sequence & nSequence. The input transaction ([a033314920217835846d36c357c459b7badda78133b49a227b6ddcd0ce5c2f4e](https://blockstream.info/testnet/tx/a033314920217835846d36c357c459b7badda78133b49a227b6ddcd0ce5c2f4e)) utilizes an nSequence of (0xfffffffd) which after formatting will become (0xFDFFFFFF) so the step 3 for hashSequence has changed. Subsequently its double hash for this step also changed.
- Step 8. Hash Outputs & Outputs. For the original outputs, I used `e803000000000000 16 0014149185A045594EDDD9C1A895A75D1A5FEAE2C343` which is the amount to spent in little endian with the Bitcoin opcodes of `OP_0 <pubkey hash>` but I changed it to the `OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 <pubkey hash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG`. I have added two transactions but the recipient address is not what I want so this has to be updated later on.

Future Questions:

- What happens if there is an input with vins containing multiple inputs and each vins input uses a different nSequence, then which nSequence should be used to generate the transaction signature ?